# ServiceStack on server and .NET Compact Framework client

Tags: rest, compact-framework, servicestack

I created my server and clients (MonoDroid and Windows) with ServiceStack, everything works very well, but now I need to consume the data from the server with a mobile client with Compact Framework F3.5.

I can access it as SOAP webservice, but I would prefer to go through REST, and use a framework to simplify things, just like the ServiceStack client (that as RestSharp is not compatible with the Compact Framework).

Do you know of something compatible with CF3.5 that lets me connect with a ServiceStack server in an easy way as

```
var client = new JsonServiceClient("http://192.168.0.87:82");
HelloResponse response = client.Get(new Hello { Name = "World!" });
```

UPDATE:

I managed to get the response with HTTPWebRequest and deserialize my HelloResponse object with an old JSON.Net version that supports the .NET Compact Framework.
The only thing that I'm missing is how to serialize my hypothetical HelloReq object and pass it to the HttpWebRequest, any hint? (without having to manually create the route as below)

```
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://192.168.0.87:82/Hello/test?format=json");
req.Method = "GET";           
HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
Stream respStream = resp.GetResponseStream();
string resps;

using (var reader = new StreamReader(respStream, Encoding.UTF8))
{
      resps = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
respStream.Close();

JsonTextReader jreader = new JsonTextReader(new StringReader(resps));

JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
HelloResponse p = serializer.Deserialize<HelloResponse>(jreader);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Request created:

```
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://192.168.0.87:82/json/syncreply/Hello");
            req.ContentType = "text/json";
            req.Method = "POST";
            req.ContentLength = json.Length;

            using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(req.GetRequestStream()))
            {
                streamWriter.Write(json);
                streamWriter.Flush();
                streamWriter.Close();
            }
```